# How to configure jetty to listen to multiple ports?

Tags: web-server, port, jetty

I just want to configure jetty to listen to more than one port. I don't want multiple instances nor multiple webapps, just one jetty, one webapp, but listening to 2 or more ports.

The default way does not support multiple entries:

```
<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your jetty.xml you have something like this

```
<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" default="x.y.z.v"/></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="80"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Just duplicate this block and change the port in the duplicate.

Comment: That was my first approach, however, something didn't work. Now I tried it again, without problems. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried the same thing - but cannot get jetty to listen on additional ports

Comment: if it matters, I'm on Jetty 6.1 (an older app I am not in the position of being able to update)

Comment: How to do the same thing in Jetty 10?

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/operations-guide/index.html#og-protocols